# Compound interest computation on a "non continuous" asset

Tags: calculus, finance

Suppose that there is some equity which yields revenues, when locked in a revenue program.

This equity costs $X$ dollars per unit, and gives $Y$ dollars per unit per second, while the program duration is $Z$ seconds.

Whenever a sufficient amount of revenues has accumulated, it is immediately converted into a new unit, which is then added to the program, producing yet even more revenues.

So when locking $N$ units in that revenue program, I ultimately get back $N$ or more units, and up to $X$ minus epsilon dollars (since more than that would be converted into units).

For example, if:

- $X = 60$ (each unit costs $60$ dollars)
- $Y = 0.5$ (each unit yields $0.5$ dollars per second)
- $Z = 80$ (the program duration is $80$ seconds)
- $N = 4$ (locking $4$ units in the program)

Then the flow would be:

```
+------+---------+---------------------------------------+------------------------+
| time | elapsed | calculation                           | total equity           |
+------+---------+---------------------------------------+------------------------+
|   0  |         |                                       |  0 dollars and 4 units |
|  30  | 30      | 4 * 0.5 * 30 = 60 dollars and 4 units |  0 dollars and 5 units |
|  54  | 24      | 5 * 0.5 * 24 = 60 dollars and 5 units |  0 dollars and 6 units |
|  74  | 20      | 6 * 0.5 * 20 = 60 dollars and 6 units |  0 dollars and 7 units |
|  80  |  6      | 7 * 0.5 *  6 = 21 dollars and 7 units | 21 dollars and 7 units |
+------+---------+---------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

What general purpose formula can I use in order to calculate the bottom line?

For example, in this case, given:

- $X = 60$
- $Y = 0.5$
- $Z = 80$
- $N = 4$

I want to compute the two outputs of `21 dollars` and `7 units`.

I feel like I should be using some sort of 'compound interest' here, but I'm not really sure how to achieve that.

Thank you very much.

**UPDATE:**

I believe that in the example above, I need to solve $\sum\limits_{n=4}^{k}\frac{60}{0.5n}=80$ for $k$.

Then the total number of units is $\lceil{k}\rceil$, and the total number of dollars can probably be easily computed following that.

So the general formula to solve for $k$ would be:

$$\sum\limits_{n=N}^{k}\frac{X}{Yn}=Z$$

Is that correct, and if yes, then is there a straightforward (non-iterative) way for solving it?

Comment: The equation cannot be solved algebraically. Basically the sum gives a result where the [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) is involved.

Comment: @callculus42: Thank you. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bn%3DN%7D%5E%7Bx%7D%5Cfrac%7BA%7D%7BBn%7D%3DC) suggests using the [Digamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), for which the approximation that I'd need to solve for $k$ is $\color\red{\ln(k+1)-\frac1{2k+2} = YZ/X+\ln(N)-\frac1{2N}}$, so it does seem impossible algebraically.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I would recommend to try out some values for $k$. This probably the fastest and easiest method.

Answer (score 1):

As Wolfram Alpha gave it
$$\sum\limits_{n=N}^{k}\frac{X}{Yn}=Z \implies \psi (k+1)=\psi (N)+\frac{Y Z}{X}$$ Using harmonic numbers instead
$$H_k=H_{n-1}+\frac{Y Z}{X}=A$$

Assuming that $k$ could be large, we could use
$$H_k=\log (k)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2 k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$ and neglecting the higher order terms
$$k=-\frac{1}{2 W\left(-\frac{1}{2}e^{\gamma -A}\right)}\tag 1$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

You also could find very good approximations based on series (have a look at sequences $A118050$ and $A118050$ in $OEIS$ for the coefficients).

You can also have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4398047/approximation-of-harmonic-numbers-and-their-analytical-inverse).

For illustration, using $(1)$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1.5 & 1.94619 &  2.00000 \\
 2.0 & 3.61240 &  3.63868 \\
 2.5 & 6.31967 &  6.33390 \\
 3.0 & 10.7654 &  10.7735 \\
 3.5 & 18.0860 &  18.0907 \\
 4.0 & 30.1505 &  30.1533 \\
 4.5 & 50.0385 &  50.0401 \\
 5.0 & 82.8265 &  82.8275
\end{array}
\right)$$