# Exponentially Increasing Speed

Tags: functions, recursion, hyperoperation

A person starts running at 1m/s

Every metre they run, they gain 1m/s in speed. What is a function that describes their speed at time t (metres per second) and their distance at time t (in metres)?

Assuming the person can run for as long as possible, laws of physics don't apply, and they don't have a speed cap.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The question is stated incompletely, so it cannot be answered, because the acceleration is specified not in differential form but in finite first differences form. To get a full solution of these differential equations, one must not merely state what the difference in speeds is after one meter, but also what the difference is at all differentially different times or locations (after 0.01 meters, after 0.001 meters,....).

Comment: The speed appears to be increasing linearly rather than exponentially.

Comment: For the distance $d \in \mathbb{N}$ you would get $t(d)=\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{1}{i}$. If you want to calculate the inverse, you need to find the inverse of the harmonic sum.

Comment: Do they get the speed boosts continuously, or at discrete 1 meter intervals?

Answer (score 1):

Using @garondal's comment
$$t_d=\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{1}{i}=H_d$$ there is an approximate inverse of the harmonic number (have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4398047/approximation-of-harmonic-numbers-and-their-analytical-inverse)).

Using  @Gary's comments,
$$d \sim  x-\frac 12 -\frac 1{24 x}+\frac 3{640 x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad x=e^{t_d- \gamma }$$